# jQuery UI Widget in a jQueryUI Widget

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have got a problem to display a jQueryUI Widget in a jQueryUI Widget. [Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/7eA7d/) 
The displayed content div of the inner widget is wrong. It´s on the same position as the tabs. I think it's a css problem, but i can not find a solution without changing the css. I thought, a widget is sealed from other "objects"....

Please, can somebody give me a little hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your HTML.
You closed your second `<ul>` in the wrong place.
Try this:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Exterieur</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Interieur</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Ausstattung</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-4">Einstellungen</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <div id="ext">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#felgen">Felgen</a></li>
            <li><a href="#lack">Lack</a></li>
         </ul>
         <div id="felgen">Felgen...</div>
         <div id="lack">Lack...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">zwei</div>
    <div id="tabs-3">drei</div>
    <div id="tabs-4">vier</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I miss the error in the html structure...So, no work before the first coffee...